# Library not found error in D language program

Tags: d

When i run D language program in ubuntu 14.0 i got this library not found error.

```
 Sys_LoadLibrary error: libphobos2.so.0.83: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Where can i found this library?

Comment: it comes with the dmd distribution.i would try installing it from the packages too and see what happens

Comment: The question title has "Library not fond error", which seemed to mean the Library is distant, cold, and aloof.